# How to add build steps in Qt Creator for every project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, meson-build, custom-build-step

Using Qt Creator (latest released version, "Qt Creator 5.0.3 based on Qt 5.15.2"), the default build steps when creating a new project using meson are wrong.

My project configuration is the following: I have my source code, meson build files in a directory which also contains the build directory named "build".

Here are the default build steps:
[image]

Here is what it should be:

[image]

Is there a way I can change the default build settings for every project? Can someone explain why Qt Creator doesn't have good build steps by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Options > Meson > Enable "Autorun meson".
Yeah, that's an easy fix.